# Changes in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.04, 20.10

I today updated my Ubuntu 20.04 Long Term Support version to Ubuntu 20.10. Can anyone tell me what are changes that were made to 20.10 version? The only change that I can see is the background. So can anyone exactly tell me what were the changes made to 20.10 version.

As I am a beginner to Ubuntu, I don't know what was exactly changed to Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Detailed information about Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy Gorilla (or any other version) can be found in its *release notes* (also called *changelog* for some other software). See:

- ### [Groovy Gorilla Release Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/groovy-gorilla-release-notes/15533/1)